# Adding lines to Python Files for Debugging

Tags: python, file

I am trying to write a script in Python which will read any python script searching for function definitions and add a print statement inside the function for debugging purpose.

e.g.

```
def function_for_test:
    print "this line should be added for debugging purpose"
    more code here....
    more code here....
```

so far I have this code

```
import os
import re
import sys

match_class = re.compile(r'^[ \t]*(def|class)[ \t]+([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)[ \t]*[:\(]')


for root, dirs, files in  os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
        for fn in files:
                if fn.endswith(".py"):
                        with open(os.path.join(root, fn), "r+") as source:
                                        while True:
                                                line = source.readline()
                                                if line == "": break
                                                m = match_class.match(line.expandtabs())
                                                if m:
                                                        print m.groups()
```

I have run in to trouble because if I try to write text, the existing text is getting over written. Could anyone please suggest some way to overcome this. I don't want to create another file for this purpose and copy text from original to new file with modifications

Comment: Have you considered using the sys.settrace function. This can be used to execute a function every time one of your functions is executed, so might satisfy your requirement without the need for parsing and modifying the package source?>

Comment: I will try to read about settrace.... What I need is that whenever any function from the project gets executed, it prints output to the commandline or to a text file; this way I can traceout the entire flow of the project. I shouldn't have used the word debugging...I need to trace all the functions that are being called when I perform some action using the program. e.g. If I were to click on a GUI button, if all the functions in the source would go and print a line in a text file when they are called, this way I could know which functions are being called.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of adding content to a file without rewriting all the downstream content.

You can use the following logic:

```
with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    modified_lines = instrument_code(lines)

    f.seek(0)  # Go back to file start
    f.writelines(modified_lines)

    # Remove trailing content in case your file is shorter than original
    f.truncate()
```

Where `instrument_code` is your code that modifies the source file.

Answer (score 1):

Settrace can potentially be used to meet this requirement. Be aware that there will be a performance overhead, and there may well be a better way.. But, this might be a quick (from a coding point of view) way to meet your requirement.

For example

```
import sys

def trace_f(frame, event, arg):
    if event == "call":
        print 'Execute {f} '.format(f=frame.f_code)
```

Now defining a trivial sample function to trace

```
def multiply_by_two(x):
    print x*2
```

And activate tracing

```
sys.settrace(trace_f)

multiply_by_two(12)
```